# Place Image Item above GalleryView

Tags: android, view, gallery, image-gallery

I have a problem with my GalleryView. I need an image above the Gallery but this image is not moving with gallery. How to I can put an item above GalleryView? Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use a ImageView above your gallery, in your layout.

Comment: but the image have opacity and below it i need see the galery.

Comment: You can set the gallery below the imageview? What do you mean it has opacity? You can set the opacity of the view..yes.